# Find value range of $2^x+2^y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assume $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ satisfy $$4^x+4^y = 2^{x+1} + 2^{y+1}$$, Find the value range of $$2^x+2^y$$

---

I know $x=y=1$ is a solution of $4^x+4^y = 2^{x+1} + 2^{y+1}$ , but I can't go further more. I can only find one solution pair of $4^x+4^y = 2^{x+1} + 2^{y+1}$. It seems very far from solve this question...

Comment: $$2^x(2^x-1)=2^y(1-2^y)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = 2^x, b = 2^y$. Use some algebraic manipulation to arrive at $(a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2 = 2$

This is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at $(1, 1)$, and we want to find the minimum and maximum values of $a + b$.

So $a + b = M \rightarrow b = -a + M$, which is the equation of a line with slope $-1$. The maximum and minimum will be when we find the maximum and minimum y-intercept of this line such that it intersects at least one point on the circle with $a, b > 0$

It's tangent to the circle at the top right when $a = b = 2$ which gives a value of $M = 4$. The smallest y-intercept occurs at $m = 2$, however, we do not include $2$ because it makes one of the coordinates zero. This establishes $(2, 4]$ as the range.

Answer (score 1):

So, then the another solution:

let $f(x) = 2^x$. Then we can go to that form of equation:

$$(f(x)-1)^2 + (f(y)-1)^2 = 2$$

We got a circle. If we consider points of intersection of this circle with a lines $$f(x)+f(y) = const$$ we can get an answer.

We should also be polite with restrictions $f(x),f(y) > 0$.

If we draw a picture, we will conclude that range is (2, 4].

Comment: Upper Bound will be $4$, not $1+\sqrt {2}$. Check your calculations.

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy, you're right. there was a mistake.

Comment: It sometimes happens.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality allows us to conclude $$((a-1)^{2}+(b-1)^{2})(1+1) \geq (a-1+b-1)^{2}$$ and hence $4\geq (a+b-2)^{2}$ and finally $a+b \leq 4$ with equality holding only when $a=b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a=2^x$, $b=2^y$, then the problem is equivalent to finding the range of $a+b$ where $a,b>0$ and
$$a^2+b^2=2a+2b$$
Without loss of generality $a\ge b$ and we can make the substitution $c=a+b$, $d=a-b$, so now $c>d\ge0$, and we require
\begin{align*}\left(\frac{c+d}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{c-d}2\right)^2&=(c+d)+(c-d)\\
c^2+2cd+d^2+c^2-2cd+d^2&=8c\\
c^2+d^2&=4c\end{align*}
Observe that
$$c^2\le c^2+d^2=4c\Longleftrightarrow c(c-4)\le0\Longleftrightarrow c\le4$$
and
$$2c^2>c^2+d^2=4c\Longleftrightarrow c(c-2)>0\Longleftrightarrow c>2$$
It's easy to see all such values can be attained and the answer is the interval $(2,4]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $2^{x}=a,2^{y}=b,$where $a,b\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{+}$. Then we have $a^{2}+b^{2}=2(a+b)$ which is equivalent to $%
(a-1)^{2}+(b-1)^{2}=2.$So we take the part of the circle  with center $M(1,1)
$ and radius $r=\sqrt{2}$ in the first district of the plane as the domain of the
function $f(a,b)=a+b$. We are looking for maxium and minium values of $f$ in
the given domain. Any point $(a,b)$ in the domain is $\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$
units far from $(0,0)$ which is also in the given circle (though not in
domain). We also know that two points on a circle are at most diameter
length far from each other. So $\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}=2\sqrt{2}$ at most. Thus $%
a^{2}+b^{2}=8.$ Then we have $2(a+b)=8$ and finally $a+b=4$ at maximum. We
look at the edges (because they are closer to (0,0) ) of the domain for
mininum value which is at $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$. Then $a+b$ converges to $2$ at
minimum. We have the value range $(2,4]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$(2^x+2^y)^2=4^x+4^y+2^{x+y+1}=2^{x+1}+2^{y+1}+2^{x+y+1}$$

If $a=2^x$, $b=2^y$, then

$$(a+b)^2=2(a+b+ab)>2(a+b)$$

so $a+b>2$.

I'm looking for an upper bound. If I find it, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Yes. And by hypothesis, $4^x+4^y=2^{x+1}+2^{y+1}$.

Comment: Okay. Though you don't really have justification for why your lower bound is tight.

Answer (score -3):

Let $\delta x = y-x$ and $x\ge y$. Then

$$4^x(1+4^{\delta x}) = 2^{x+1}(1+2^{\delta x})$$

then from factorization we can claim that:

$$2x = x+1 ~\text{and}~~ 4^{\delta x} = 2^{\delta x}$$

So, we get $x = y = 1$.

Comment: $x,y\in\mathbb R$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are *real* numbers.